# Getting confidence interval of parameter estimate

Tags: matlab, regression, tostring, curve-fitting, confidence-interval

Using the `cftool` when a regression line it fitted, by default it shows the 95% confidence bounds for the parameter estimates as

```
Linear model Poly1:
     f(x) = p1*x + p2

Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p1 =         ...  (..., ...)
   p2 =         ...  (..., ...)
```

Is there a way to get the **99%** confidence interval using this curve fitting tool box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`confint`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cfit.confint.html) method of the `cfit` object:

```
ci = confint(fitresult, 0.99)
```

You might want to take a look at the documentation article titled "[Fit Postprocessing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit-postprocessing.html)".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have fitted the regression line with `cftool`. So, how can I call this `confint` method then? I then did regression using `\` operator and found a way to find the confidence interval using `[b,bint,r,rint,stats]  = regress(y,X,0.01);`. I hope this gives the correct CI as well.

Comment: If you use `cftool` then **export the fit object** or use the `fit` method directly, you get a `cfit` object (that would be the `fitresult` which appears in my answer). If you're using the `mldivide` operator (`\ `), it only gives you the least-squares estimate of the coefficients, without the error bounds at all. You'll have to compute the error on your own based on the fit coefficients then use coefficients from the t-distribution etc. You have asked specifically about `cfit` - which allow us to take a shortcut.